# Visual Studio Interaction command not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have an issue with my project within Visual Studio that whenever I attempt to reference the Microsoft Visual Basic dll, none of the commands are showing or working within the project.

I've used the dll in projects before and I can't understand why it's not working in this one. I've referenced the dll using `using Microsoft.VisualBasic;` but whenever I want to use the `Interaction.InputBox("Not Working");` command it's not showing or just gives me the error "The name 'Interaction' does not exist in the current context".

Am I being an idiot and missing something here or is there something else that is causing it to not work?
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/325961

1. In a Visual C# application, click the Project menu, and then click Add Reference.
2. In the Component Name list, click Microsoft Visual Basic .NET Runtime to add Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll.

You can now use members of the Visual Basic .NET run-time library in Visual C#

Comment: I thought I was just being an idiot, haha thank you very much, I must have just forgot this step but couldn't figure it out, thanks!

Comment: Just for anyone else landing on this page:  you can also go to Add Reference and search for Microsoft.VisualBasic under Assemblies > Frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

In a Visual C# application, click the Project menu, and then click Add Reference.
In the Component Name list, click Microsoft Visual Basic .NET Runtime to add Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll.
You can now use members of the Visual Basic .NET run-time library in Visual C#

it works 4/03/2021